# Copy of Wikipedia in tag wiki

Tags: discussion, tag-wikis, copyright

After approving a tag edit, I realized it was a copy of an article of Wikipedia. The editor did the same on another tag, and I see in his history there are other cases.

In both cases, there is a link to wikipedia on a term in the tag description, but no real attribution. I don't think the [Wikipedia license](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Copyrights) allows that.

Do you think it's ok here? If not, it should be enough to revert the edits and tell the editor to stop copying. Or, alternately, to give proper attribution, as the Stack Exchange license seems compatible (CC-BY-SA 3.0).

The edits I reviewed: [hilbert-polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/hilbert-polynomial/info), [pattern-matching](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/pattern-matching/info)

Comment: It might be useful to include also a link directly to the suggested edit in question: https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1197429 and https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1197433.

Comment: Some related discussions in the past on meta: [Tag-wiki edits from Wikipedia](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/22617) and in chat: [tag-wikis based on Wikipedia](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3740/conversation/tag-wikis-based-on-wikipedia). (Possibly there are other discussions on this meta which I missed?) I will also add link to MathOverflow Meta post: [Should tag-wiki include a source where it is taken from?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3547) (I suppose this counts as self-promotion.)

Comment: There are also some related posts on Meta Stack Exchange, such as [Would it be OK to paste content from Wikipedia into a popular empty tag-wiki?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/79000) and some of the [posts linked there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/79000).

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks for the links. Apparently giving the link is enough, so there is actually no problem. I would have expected an explicit reference to Wikipedia, but I was probably wrong.

Comment: FWIW, the suggested wiki on [tag:pattern-matching] should be rejected as 'copied content' because SE is not really a replacement of Wikipedia (even if it's attributed). [How should copied content be formatted in tag wikis?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/280154) might be helpful.

Comment: @AndrewT.: To expand a bit on your point, the Wikipedia article begins with "This article is about pattern matching in functional programming."  Thus there the meaning of *pattern matching" is taken in (potentially) a more limited or even disjoint sense than it should be for Math.SE purposes.  I don't object to linking to that Wikipedia article, but the idea tag-info here would include advice about tag usage that would be exogenous to the Wikipedia article.

Comment: Even if there was no legal problem, copying from Wikipedia is both morally wrong and lazy.